# Relationships between almost sure convergence, convergence in density, and convergence in moments

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I've been trying to map out the relationships between the modes of convergence associated with random variables. However, I've had a hard time finding out online whether the statements below are true or not. I was wondering if anyone can also give me intuition as to why are true o aside from a proof or counterexample.

1) Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables with probability density function $f_n$. Suppose that $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. such that $X$ has density $f$. Does it follow that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in some sense? Perhaps pointwise, in $L^1$, etc.?

2) Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables with density $f_n$. Suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and that $\int f \,dx = 1$. Let $X$ be a random variable whose density is $f$. Do the moments of $X_n$ converge to the moments of $X$?